# Errors installing package from github

Tags: r

Im trying to install the "Mage" package from Github but I receive a long string of errors.

I've installed other packages from the same Github Repo without any problems but the Mage package doesn't seem to work.

I've tried using devtools and remotes to install the package but both return the same string of errors.

```
> devtools::install_github("jonesor/compadreDB/Mage")
Downloading GitHub repo jonesor/compadreDB@master
✔  checking for file ‘/private/var/folders/7n/vbkk0vpx04jgqffc38wn70vh0000gn/T/Rtmpkny6ys/remotes109a646e7fc4/jonesor-compadreDB-be4a17f/Mage/DESCRIPTION’ ...
─  preparing ‘Mage’:
✔  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
   Warning: /private/var/folders/7n/vbkk0vpx04jgqffc38wn70vh0000gn/T/RtmpjODb6Y/Rbuild13de453af87e/Mage/man/R_0.Rd:17: unexpected section header '\name'
   Warning: /private/var/folders/7n/vbkk0vpx04jgqffc38wn70vh0000gn/T/RtmpjODb6Y/Rbuild13de453af87e/Mage/man/R_0.Rd:24: unexpected section header '\arguments'
   Warning: /private/var/folders/7n/vbkk0vpx04jgqffc38wn70vh0000gn/T/RtmpjODb6Y/Rbuild13de453af87e/Mage/man/R_0.Rd:25: unknown macro '\item'
   Warning: /private/var/folders/7n/vbkk0vpx04jgqffc38wn70vh0000gn/T/RtmpjODb6Y/Rbuild13de453af87e/Mage/man/R_0.Rd:28: unknown macro '\item'
   Warning: /private/var/folders/7n/vbkk0vpx04jgqffc38wn70vh0000gn/T/RtmpjODb6Y/Rbuild13de453af87e/Mage/man/R_0.Rd:31: unknown macro '\item'
   Warning: /private/var/folders/7n/vbkk0vpx04jgqffc38wn70vh0000gn/T/RtmpjODb6Y/Rbuild13de453af87e/Mage/man/R_0.Rd:34: unexpected section header '\value'
   Warning: /private/var/folders/7n/vbkk0vpx04jgqffc38wn70vh0000gn/T/RtmpjODb6Y/Rbuild13de453af87e/Mage/man/R_0.Rd:40: unexpected section header '\description'
   Warning: /private/var/folders/7n/vbkk0vpx04jgqffc38wn70vh0000gn/T/RtmpjODb6Y/Rbuild13de453af87e/Mage/man/R_0.Rd:45: unexpected section header '\details'
   Warning: /private/var/folders/7n/vbkk0vpx04jgqffc38wn70vh0000gn/T/RtmpjODb6Y/Rbuild13de453af87e/Mage/man/R_0.Rd:48: unexpected section header '\note'
   Warning: /private/var/folders/7n/vbkk0vpx04jgqffc38wn70vh0000gn/T/RtmpjODb6Y/Rbuild13de453af87e/Mage/man/R_0.Rd:51: unexpected section header '\examples'
   Warning: /private/var/folders/7n/vbkk0vpx04jgqffc38wn70vh0000gn/T/RtmpjODb6Y/Rbuild13de453af87e/Mage/man/R_0.Rd:61: unexpected section header '\references'
   Warning: /private/var/folders/7n/vbkk0vpx04jgqffc38wn70vh0000gn/T/RtmpjODb6Y/Rbuild13de453af87e/Mage/man/R_0.Rd:66: unexpected section header '\seealso'
   Warning: /private/var/folders/7n/vbkk0vpx04jgqffc38wn70vh0000gn/T/RtmpjODb6Y/Rbuild13de453af87e/Mage/man/R_0.Rd:69: unexpected section header '\author'
   Warning: /private/var/folders/7n/vbkk0vpx04jgqffc38wn70vh0000gn/T/RtmpjODb6Y/Rbuild13de453af87e/Mage/man/R_0.Rd:74: unexpected section header '\keyword'
   Warning: /private/var/folders/7n/vbkk0vpx04jgqffc38wn70vh0000gn/T/RtmpjODb6Y/Rbuild13de453af87e/Mage/man/matrixElementPerturbation.Rd:12: unknown macro '\item'
   Warning: /private/var/folders/7n/vbkk0vpx04jgqffc38wn70vh0000gn/T/RtmpjODb6Y/Rbuild13de453af87e/Mage/man/matrixElementPerturbation.Rd:14: unknown macro '\item'
   Warning: /private/var/folders/7n/vbkk0vpx04jgqffc38wn70vh0000gn/T/RtmpjODb6Y/Rbuild13de453af87e/Mage/man/matrixElementPerturbation.Rd:16: unknown macro '\item'
   Warning: /private/var/folders/7n/vbkk0vpx04jgqffc38wn70vh0000gn/T/RtmpjODb6Y/Rbuild13de453af87e/Mage/man/matrixElementPerturbation.Rd:18: unexpected section header '\value'
   Warning: /private/var/folders/7n/vbkk0vpx04jgqffc38wn70vh0000gn/T/RtmpjODb6Y/Rbuild13de453af87e/Mage/man/matrixElementPerturbation.Rd:21: unexpected section header '\description'
   Warning: /private/var/folders/7n/vbkk0vpx04jgqffc38wn70vh0000gn/T/RtmpjODb6Y/Rbuild13de453af87e/Mage/man/matrixElementPerturbation.Rd:24: unexpected section header '\details'
   Warning: /private/var/folders/7n/vbkk0vpx04jgqffc38wn70vh0000gn/T/RtmpjODb6Y/Rbuild13de453af87e/Mage/man/matrixElementPerturbation.Rd:27: unexpected section header '\note'
   Warning: /private/var/folders/7n/vbkk0vpx04jgqffc38wn70vh0000gn/T/RtmpjODb6Y/Rbuild13de453af87e/Mage/man/matrixElementPerturbation.Rd:30: unexpected section header '\examples'
   Warning: /private/var/folders/7n/vbkk0vpx04jgqffc38wn70vh0000gn/T/RtmpjODb6Y/Rbuild13de453af87e/Mage/man/matrixElementPerturbation.Rd:40: unexpected section header '\references'
   Warning: /private/var/folders/7n/vbkk0vpx04jgqffc38wn70vh0000gn/T/RtmpjODb6Y/Rbuild13de453af87e/Mage/man/matrixElementPerturbation.Rd:43: unexpected section header '\seealso'
   Warning: /private/var/folders/7n/vbkk0vpx04jgqffc38wn70vh0000gn/T/RtmpjODb6Y/Rbuild13de453af87e/Mage/man/matrixElementPerturbation.Rd:46: unexpected section header '\author'
   Warning: /private/var/folders/7n/vbkk0vpx04jgqffc38wn70vh0000gn/T/RtmpjODb6Y/Rbuild13de453af87e/Mage/man/matrixElementPerturbation.Rd:49: unexpected section header '\keyword'
   Warning: /private/var/folders/7n/vbkk0vpx04jgqffc38wn70vh0000gn/T/RtmpjODb6Y/Rbuild13de453af87e/Mage/man/matrixElementPerturbation.Rd:50: unexpected section header '\keyword'
   Warning: /private/var/folders/7n/vbkk0vpx04jgqffc38wn70vh0000gn/T/RtmpjODb6Y/Rbuild13de453af87e/Mage/man/matrixElementPerturbation.Rd:51: unexpected END_OF_INPUT '
   '
   Warning: /private/var/folders/7n/vbkk0vpx04jgqffc38wn70vh0000gn/T/RtmpjODb6Y/Rbuild13de453af87e/Mage/man/vitalRatePerturbation.Rd:12: unknown macro '\item'
   Warning: /private/var/folders/7n/vbkk0vpx04jgqffc38wn70vh0000gn/T/RtmpjODb6Y/Rbuild13de453af87e/Mage/man/vitalRatePerturbation.Rd:14: unknown macro '\item'
   Warning: /private/var/folders/7n/vbkk0vpx04jgqffc38wn70vh0000gn/T/RtmpjODb6Y/Rbuild13de453af87e/Mage/man/vitalRatePerturbation.Rd:16: unknown macro '\item'
   Warning: /private/var/folders/7n/vbkk0vpx04jgqffc38wn70vh0000gn/T/RtmpjODb6Y/Rbuild13de453af87e/Mage/man/vitalRatePerturbation.Rd:18: unexpected section header '\value'
   Warning: /private/var/folders/7n/vbkk0vpx04jgqffc38wn70vh0000gn/T/RtmpjODb6Y/Rbuild13de453af87e/Mage/man/vitalRatePerturbation.Rd:21: unexpected section header '\description'
   Warning: /private/var/folders/7n/vbkk0vpx04jgqffc38wn70vh0000gn/T/RtmpjODb6Y/Rbuild13de453af87e/Mage/man/vitalRatePerturbation.Rd:24: unexpected section header '\details'
   Warning: /private/var/folders/7n/vbkk0vpx04jgqffc38wn70vh0000gn/T/RtmpjODb6Y/Rbuild13de453af87e/Mage/man/vitalRatePerturbation.Rd:27: unexpected section header '\note'
   Warning: /private/var/folders/7n/vbkk0vpx04jgqffc38wn70vh0000gn/T/RtmpjODb6Y/Rbuild13de453af87e/Mage/man/vitalRatePerturbation.Rd:30: unexpected section header '\examples'
   Warning: /private/var/folders/7n/vbkk0vpx04jgqffc38wn70vh0000gn/T/RtmpjODb6Y/Rbuild13de453af87e/Mage/man/vitalRatePerturbation.Rd:40: unexpected section header '\references'
   Warning: /private/var/folders/7n/vbkk0vpx04jgqffc38wn70vh0000gn/T/RtmpjODb6Y/Rbuild13de453af87e/Mage/man/vitalRatePerturbation.Rd:43: unexpected section header '\seealso'
   Warning: /private/var/folders/7n/vbkk0vpx04jgqffc38wn70vh0000gn/T/RtmpjODb6Y/Rbuild13de453af87e/Mage/man/vitalRatePerturbation.Rd:46: unexpected section header '\author'
   Warning: /private/var/folders/7n/vbkk0vpx04jgqffc38wn70vh0000gn/T/RtmpjODb6Y/Rbuild13de453af87e/Mage/man/vitalRatePerturbation.Rd:49: unexpected section header '\keyword'
   Warning: /private/var/folders/7n/vbkk0vpx04jgqffc38wn70vh0000gn/T/RtmpjODb6Y/Rbuild13de453af87e/Mage/man/vitalRatePerturbation.Rd:50: unexpected section header '\keyword'
   Warning: /private/var/folders/7n/vbkk0vpx04jgqffc38wn70vh0000gn/T/RtmpjODb6Y/Rbuild13de453af87e/Mage/man/vitalRatePerturbation.Rd:51: unexpected END_OF_INPUT '
   '
─  installing the package to process help pages
─  saving partial Rd database (5.1s)
─  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
─  checking for empty or unneeded directories
─  building ‘Mage_0.1.tar.gz’

* installing *source* package ‘Mage’ ...
** using staged installation
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
Error : (converted from warning) /private/var/folders/7n/vbkk0vpx04jgqffc38wn70vh0000gn/T/Rtmpv2ViIa/R.INSTALL140f10d63a12/Mage/man/R_0.Rd:17: unexpected section header '\name'
ERROR: installing Rd objects failed for package ‘Mage’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/Mage’
Error: Failed to install 'Mage' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘/var/folders/7n/vbkk0vpx04jgqffc38wn70vh0000gn/T//Rtmpkny6ys/file109a1286505f/Mage_0.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Looking at [the source](https://github.com/jonesor/compadreDB/blob/master/Mage/man/R_0.Rd) for the file `R_0.Rd`, it doesn't look right. There are characters in the file that should not be there, apparently from an error during a git commit/push. I would raise an issue at the Github repository.

Comment: thank you so much I will send them an email!